# Error handling with scrapy and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I have a scrapy code that scrapes a website and writes to MySQL

```
import MySQLdb.cursors

def __init__(self,stats):
    self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(<dbnam>,host=<host>,user=<user>,port=<port>,passwd=<pwd>, db=<dbname>, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)


tx.execute("""INSERT INTO numbers ('{0}').format(", ".join(item['numbers'])))
```

with the following error handle:

```
def handle_error(self, e):
    logging.error("This INSERT generated an ERROR")
```

How do I get the error description to output on the screen. I've searched a lot across the web and couldnt find a solution.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple problem after all. Maybe I misread the documentation.

`def handle_error(self, e):
        logging.info(e)`